# Shopify orders webhooks order triggered

Tags: shopify, webhooks

So I setup all the triggers on orders webhook, create update payments fulfillments.

I am trying to figure out what gets fired first. because I log the timestamp on the db. but sometimes they trigger at same time.

> update->payments->update->create

I am trying to figure out if this true?

Answer (score 0):

It is true that these actions can hit your webhook out of order.

How to deal with that depends on what you are doing.

In one case I re-queue all updates and payments if I haven't received the create yet and then re-try them.

I'll also record the order's updated_at value and ignore hooks that occur with earlier values than the last one I processed.

Comment: I might just queue them after all, maybe proccess them after like 2 minutes.